# Tomcat 8 Maven Plugin for Java 8

Tags: tomcat, java-8, maven-tomcat-plugin, tomcat8

Is the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` working with a tomcat 8 server and java 8? I can't find any `tomcat8-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not ready https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-234

Comment: Try using Cargo See answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271213/tomcat-8-integration-with-maven/41771077#41771077

Comment: Could you explain what you mean in Tomcat7-maven-plugin working with a tomcat 8 server? how you make plugin to work with stand-alone server? plugin starts its own server..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 8 integration with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271213/tomcat-8-integration-with-maven)

Answer (score 81):

Yes you can,

In your `pom.xml`, add the tomcat plugin. (You can use this for both Tomcat 7 and 8):

**`pom.xml`**

```
<!-- Tomcat plugin -->  
<plugin>  
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
 <version>2.2</version>  
 <configuration>  
  <url>http:// localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  
  <server>TomcatServer</server>    *(From maven > settings.xml)*
  <username>*yourtomcatusername*</username>  
  <password>*yourtomcatpassword*</password>   
 </configuration>   
</plugin>
```

**`tomcat-users.xml`**

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>  
        <role rolename="manager-script"/>   
        <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />  
</tomcat-users>
```

**`settings.xml` (maven > conf)**

```
<servers>  
    <server>
       <id>TomcatServer</id>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

*** deploy/re-deploy**

**`mvn tomcat7:deploy`** OR
**`mvn tomcat7:redeploy`**

*Tried this on (Both Ubuntu and Windows 8/10):*

- Jdk 7 & Tomcat 7
- Jdk 7 & Tomcat 8
- Jdk 8 & Tomcat 7
- Jdk 8 & Tomcat 8
- Jdk 8 & Tomcat 9

Tested on Both Jdk 7/8 & Tomcat 7/8. (Works with Tomcat 8.5 and 9)

**Note:**
*Tomcat manager should be running or properly setup, before you can use it with maven.*

Good Luck!

Comment: >  mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Comment: that's nice only if you have tomcat on your local PC. Doesn't solve the problem for embedded tomcat

Comment: Putting the username and password in the POM is redundant and a security risk (especially if you check your code into a repository). The whole point of identifying the server by ID in the POM is so that Maven can look up the username and password in the user-specific settings file (not checked into source control). But otherwise this post was really helpful---thanks.

Comment: tomcat7-maven-plugin, what does 7 stands for? Is it java version or tomcat version. Can I use tomcat7-maven-plugin with Tomcat-9?

Comment: Where can I find the following files: tomcat-users.xml - (PROJECT_NAME\target\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml?), settings.xml - (???). I have maven project but still can't figure it out

Comment: In this solution, it uses a separate apache tomcat installed and you can find in the location or path where you installed tomcat (or extracted if coming from a zip or tar.gz file). For example, C:\apache-tomcat-8\conf\tomcat-users.xml. If you are in ubuntu... example would be /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

Comment: @BorgyManotoy _"will test Tomcat 9 soon"_ – did you try?

Comment: I just did and it works... just note that when you update maven, you might lose the old configuration. Goodluck!

Comment: Is it possible that I deploy my app with the plugin only without the tomcat server installed?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I am not sure if it is advisable to deploy/run the application with just plugin, when in production mode.

Answer (score 6):

Plugin run Tomcat 7.0.47:

`mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run`

```
 ...
 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

This is sample to run plugin with Tomcat 8 and Java 8: [Cargo embedded tomcat: custom context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587299/cargo-embedded-tomcat-custom-context-xml#38234234)

Answer (score 1):

Almost 2 years later....
 This github [project readme](https://github.com/NitorCreations/tomcat8-war-runner#readme) has a some clarity of configuration of the maven plugin and it seems, according to this [apache github project](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin), the plugin itself will materialise soon enough.

Comment: linking my answer through this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370927/jenkins-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat-8

Answer (score 0):

Since November 2017, one can use tomcat8-maven-plugin:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that this plugin resides in ICM repo (not in Maven Central), hence you should add the repo to your pluginsRepositories in your pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>icm</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: tried but saw `Could not transfer artifact org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat8-maven-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to icm (http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo): Authentication failed for http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/org/apache/tomcat/maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin/2.2/tomcat8-maven-plugin-2.2.pom 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: Moreover, it is not secure to download anything on your laptop from third-party like http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory

Answer (score 0):

An other solution (if possible) would be to use TomEE instead of Tomcat, which has a working maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Version 7.1.1 wraps a Tomcat 8.5.41

Answer (score -1):

groupId and Mojo name change
Since version 2.0-beta-1 tomcat mojos has been renamed to tomcat6 and tomcat7 with the same goals.

You must configure your pom to use this new groupId:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Or add the groupId in your settings.xml

....
    org.apache.tomcat.maven
    ....