# Can tomcat7 maven plugin used in to configure Tomcat8 Server - Tomcat Maven Plugin

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, tomcat8, maven-tomcat-plugin

***I am using JAVA 1.8 and Maven_3.3.9.***

Trying to automatically deploy the war file to the Tomcat8 using maven plugin.

Can I **use tomcat7 plugin to run and deploy war file with using TOMCAT 8 Server**.

If you can share any pom.xml with following best practice of structuring, It can help me to steady my basics.

**Do I need to change any  value in Settings.xml or pom.xml** for generating and deploying the war file Properly ?

Comment: @Naresh, absolutely not possible,please use tomcat8-maven-plugin to be compatible with tomcat8 server changes.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883836/tomcat-maven-plugin-for-java-8