# Deploying war file in Tomcat Using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

In my jenkins Deploy war/ear conatiner, i was able to give war file, context path, credential and Tomcat url. But i want to give "XML Configuration file URL", along with the above input. How can it be done?Do we have a seperate plugin for it. 
My war file will not contain library file so am referring it externaly using XML file.
[image: how to give the highlighted input via jenkins]

Comment: which plugin are you using for deployment?

Comment: Deploy to conatiner plugin

Answer (score 0):

[Deploy to container](https://plugins.jenkins.io/deploy) plugin is generic and does not have tomcat specific functions. So As per your configuration, `XML Configuration file URL` option will not be there. So instead searching for this in this plugin, stop using this and go for another one. Or modify your source code accordingly. Here I am attaching a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384916/5003256) for additional info to help you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternative ways are possible but i need to know if we have a solution for the above request

Comment: For the above request there is not unless and until you add a feature request or you did that feature yourself and send them PR. Because currently it isn't having any feature like that.