# How to specify WARs built in another project for integration test using tomcat8-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, tomcat, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I have two applications (Maven 'war' artifact), let's call them `Api` and `Ui`.

I want to setup a fully automated integration test that fires up `Api` and `Ui` locally before executing integration tests.

The applications are losely-coupled and so I don't want to introduce any dependency on `Api` in `Ui`s build or vice-versa.

So I want to setup a third project, `IntegratedQA` which will have dependencies on both apps.

My initial POM contains:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My question is... How exactly do I tell tomcat to launch `Api.war` and `Ui.war`, which are built in separate projects?

Answer (score 0):

Using tomcat7-maven-plugin you can customize the tomcat7:deploy to provide the war files path to deploy into tomcat environment. 
browse this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) for the documentation.

Linking another stackoverflow answer where it is specified how it will work with tomcat 8 or 9

[Jenkins deploy war file to Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370927/jenkins-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat-8)

Comment: tomcat7:deploy pushes an app to an exiting instance of tomcat? but in this case I want to fire up an embedded instance