# Tomcat one click deployment with tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

I want to setup my web application project for one-click-deployment with the tomcat7-maven-plugin.

I've configured my project as stated here: [Tomcat 8 Maven Plugin for Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883836/tomcat-maven-plugin-for-java-8)

I'm deploying to a Tomcat 8.0.14 and JDK 1.8.0_31. The web application is roughly 60 MByte big but I configured Tomcat so a war file of that size can be deployed.

However, every time I try to run: `mvn tomcat7:redeploy` or `maven tomcat7:deploy` I get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy 
(default-cli) on project my-web-app: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager:   
Connection timed out: connect
```

Now doing research I always find solutions for problems with Connection refused but none for Connection timed out.

I've tried to restart the application server several times but no changes.

There is a proxy in place but it is configured correctly in the `settings.xml` file of maven.

Does anyone have an idea why the connection timed out or where I can change the settings for the timeouts?

Here is a full stack trace running maven with the -X flag:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:
redeploy (default-cli) on project my-web-app: Cannot invoke Tomcat
manager: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on projec
t my-web-app: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat
manager
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(A
bstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execut
e(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI
mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja
va:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket
Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSoc
ketFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnect
ion(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedCli
entConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(Default
RequestDirector.java:610)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultReq
uestDirector.java:445)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttp
Client.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttp
Client.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatMa
nager.java:742)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(Tomc
atManager.java:705)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatMa
nager.java:388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.d
eployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invo
keManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(A
bstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
        ... 22 more
[DEBUG] Connection manager is shutting down
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[DEBUG] Connection manager shut down
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Greetings

Comment: seems plugin is unable to reach your tomcat installation, have you added the entry in settings.xml and or is tomcat running in a different port

Comment: I've added the server configuration with the user credentials to the `settings.xml`file. The Tomcat server is running on port 8088 and I can reach the URL given in the configuration segment of the plugin from my browser.