# JSP Parameters not accessible using ${param.xxx} using HTML form

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm following a tutorial on Udemy that explains JSPs and Servlets:
https://www.udemy.com/jsp-tutorial

The tutorial uses Eclipse + Tomcat server.

Since I'm an IntelliJ and Maven user I wanted to set up my environment using these two. So I created a Maven project from the following archetype: "org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp" and configured my POM as folllows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SomeGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloWorldJavaServerPages</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>HelloWorldJavaServerPages Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>HelloWorldJavaServerPages</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>Tomcat85Localhost</server>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>admin</password>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Set up my other properties as described here:
[Tomcat 8 Maven Plugin for Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883836/tomcat-8-maven-plugin-for-java-8)

I am able to build my project and use the tomcat plugin to deploy to the tomcat server (or manually drag the war file in the webapps folder).

Problem is that when I have the following two files:

student-form.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Student Registration Form</title></head>
<body>
<form action="student-response.jsp">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

student-response.jsp

```
<html>
<head><title>Student Confirmation Title</title></head>
<body>
    The student is confirmed: <%= request.getParameter("firstName")%> ${param.lastName}
</body>
</html>
```

The request.getParameter method works, but the ${param.lastName} does not and it simply shows up as plain text in the browser: ${param.lastName}.

Using Eclipse (without Maven) it does work for both, so I'm wondering what I'm doing actually different/wrong here and why it is not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I found out that the references between the braces are called the "Expression Language", I decided to do another search on stackoverflow and found this:
[Expression Language in JSP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)

Changing the web.xml as described in the link above made it work.

Thank you all for reading my question, the answer was quite simple actually.