# tomcat8-maven-plugin ? (emphasis on the 8!)

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat8, mvn-repo

Is there a version 8 (tomcat8) of the below?

```
<build>
    <finalName>SampleServletFinalName</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and corresponding

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

maven search does not reveal anything

https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.tomcat.maven%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the plugin is not yet ready](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-234) but you can find some workarounds here :
[Tomcat 8 Maven Plugin for Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26883836)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `tomee-maven-plugin` solves your problem as well:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

The difference here is, that you wont get a Tomcat, but TomEE. You can compare them by looking at [this](http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html) matrix.

(Version 7.1.1 wraps a Tomcat 8.5.41)