# What is the plugin name for Tomcat8 in Spring MVC maven project

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is what we use for Tomcat 7:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to know what the equivalent will be for Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 1):

if you need working on tomcat 8, no need tomcat 8 plugin, as it has not come out yet because of this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-234). 
tomcat7-maven-plugin can be used deploy to tomcat 8.

```xml
<!-- Tomcat plugin -->  
<plugin>  
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
 <version>2.2</version>  
 <configuration>  
  <url>http:// localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  
  <server>TomcatServer</server>    *(From maven > settings.xml)*
  <username>*yourtomcatusername*</username>  
  <password>*yourtomcatpassword*</password>   
 </configuration>   
</plugin>
```

for more, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883836/tomcat-8-maven-plugin-for-java-8)